# Check if value exists in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm doing an ajax call that returns JSON, which includes 3 location zip codes.

These zip codes are:

```
value2.loc1_zip
value2.loc2_zip
value2.loc3_zip
```

Then, a "search" form returns a list of zip codes within a search radius. These are:

```
zipback.zip_codes
```

and each zipcode is here:

```
zipback.zip_codes.zip_code
```

I cannot figure out how to check if `value2.loc1_zip`, `value2.loc2_zip`, or `value2.loc3_zip` are in the list of `zipback.zip_codes`

I've tried this, but it has not worked:

```
var grabbed_zips = zipback.zip_codes;
if (grabbed_zips.hasOwnProperty(value2.loc2_zip)) {
    ...stuff...
}
```

Here's the raw JSON:

```
{"counselor_posts":[{"id":"1","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","loc1_zip":"30309"},{"id":"3","firstName":"Jeff","lastName":"Kim","loc1_zip":"30315"}]}

{"zip_codes":[{"zip_code":"30324","distance":4.484},{"zip_code":"30376","distance":4.298}]}
```

Here's the actual jquery I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '...url..here...',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(zipback) {
        var grabbed_zips = zipback.zip_codes;
        $.getJSON('/scripts/get_counselor.php', function(data2) {
            $.each(data2.counselor_posts, function(name2,value2) {
                if (grabbed_zips.hasOwnProperty(value2.loc3_zip)) {
                    $(".counselor-search-results").append(cat_html2);
                }

            });
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `value2.loc1_zip`? Is it a string? And what is `zipback.zip_codes.zip_code`? I would have guessed `zip_codes` would be an array, but from the way you are using it, it doesn't look like it. Can you include the raw JSON response you are getting in your question?

Comment: `value2.loc1_zip` is a string. `zip_codes` is an array like this: `{"zip_codes":[{"zip_code":"30324","distance":4.484},{"zip_code":"30376","distance":4.298}]}`

Comment: I've updated my question to include the actual code for some clarification

Answer (score 0):

Are you using $.parseJSON to instantiate a JSON Object?
[$.parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

This will help yo manage the object. And if the object is a list, then:

```
var JSONZips = $.parseJSON('{"zips" : {"user1zip":94140, "user2zip": 94107}}');
JSONZips.zips.hasOwnProperty('user1zip');
```

This would return true.

If you need to find a specific value, then:

```
function checkForValue(json, value) {
for (key in json) {
    if (typeof (json[key]) === "object") {
        return checkForValue(json[key], value);
    } else if (json[key] === value) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the zip codes contained in the result of the form with a `map` function, then test if `some` of the zip codes you have is contained in it.

For example:

```
var zip1 = "30321", zip2 = "00000", zip3 = "01010"; //zip codes you want to test
var grabbed_zips = {"zip_codes":[{"zip_code":"30324","distance":4.484},{"zip_code":"30376","distan‌​ce":4.298}]}; //search result

//flattened array containing the zip codes in the search result
var zipCodes = grabbed_zips.zip_codes.map(function(zip){ return zip.zip_code; });

//The test you are looking for, either true or false
var someMatch = [zip1, zip2, zip3].some(function(curZip){ return zipCodes.indexOf(curZip) != -1; });
```

Two arrays are used: one containing the zip codes you have, the other derived from the zip codes in the result of the form.
The `some` method tests if one of the zip codes in the first array is equal (index!= -1) in the second one.